# Looping through a multidimensional array in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have the server passing back this JSON and I'm not sure how to loop through a 2-dimensional array in Handlebars.

```
"userSurvey":[[1],[2],[3]]
```

I know to use `{{#each userSurvey}}` but then how would I go about do the arrays inside the `usersurvey` object?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You'd have to loop 2 times:

```
{{#each userSurvey}}
  {{#each this}}
    {{ this }}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Is there any problem with non-numerical keys? (I had dated as key and I it was not able to loop through the array)

Comment: @Kermani Array in JS can only have integer as keys. Looks like you're trying to loop over an object.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case if you want to render just "123" you can do this:

```
{{#each userSurvey}}
    {{this.[0]}}
{{/each}}
```

Or even simpler, because arrays automatiaclly transform to strings:

```
{{#each userSurvey}}
    {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: And what about if you want to render just 2? I know is quite old question but is the only good documentation that I could find for this specific issue. {{this.[1]}} doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Use the #with helper
for the obj

```
{ catg: [ 'java', 'c', 'c++' ],
  quesarray: [ [ 2, 1 ], [ 0, 2, 10, 5, 11, 12 ], [ 7, 5, 3, 8, 0 ] ],
  _id: 5d778d52d410984dc4e3e278,
  username: 'student@gmail.com' }
```

if you want to access the array quesarray index wise do this

```
{{#each qset}}
{{#with quesarray}}
{{[2]}}
{{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

and output will be 7, 5, 3, 8, 0

Answer (score 0):

```
    {{#each Arr}}
        {{#each this}}
            <label>{{this.[0]}}</label> {{this.[1]}}<br>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
```

Here is my simple example to loop array of my arrays :)